# How to populate div with data from mobx store?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobx, mobx-react

I have a div with a className of results and I want to make so that when I click on the Check button the div gets populated with the info from my store: Shop1, Shop2. I added an observable field on my CardCheck component that you toggle with the onClick event handler, and when the field is true it should display all entries in the auto array.

Here is my Component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { inject, observer } from 'mobx-react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import './cardCheck.css';

@inject('auto')
@observer
class CardCheck extends Component {
  onClick = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.checked = !this.checked;
  };

  render() {
    const { auto } = this.props;

    return (
      <div>
        <div className="newsletter-container">
          <h1>Enter the ID of your card:</h1>
          <div className="center">
            <input type="number" />
            <input type="submit" value="Check" onClick={this.onClick} />
          </div>
          <div className="results">{this.checked && auto.auto.map(a => <div key={a.name} />)}</div>
        </div>
        <h1>Offers:</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

CardCheck.propTypes = {
  auto: PropTypes.shape({
    carCount: PropTypes.string
  })
};

export default CardCheck;
```

and here is my store:

```
import { observable, action, computed } from 'mobx';

class Auto {
  @observable
  auto = [
    {
      name: 'Shop1'
    },
    {
      name: 'Shop2'
    }
  ];

  @observable checked = false;

  @action showInfo

  }
}

export { Auto };
```

Right now nothing happens when I click on the Check button, why, and how can I make it finally work?

I tried iterating through the object with a loadash method but it did not populated the div, and I also tried this in the div results:

```
{this.checked &&
              auto.auto.map((a, index) => <div key={index}>{a.name}</div>)}
```

but it didn't work and it gave me this error: Do not use Array index in keys react/no-array-index-key

Comment: In your component code, your divs are empty, so you won't see anything displayed, while your second snippet does put the name. I'd recommend you to write a full example on codesandbox. https://codesandbox.io/s/

Answer (score 0):

I think you have mistyped with `checked` field. It should be `this.auto.checked`

Comment: changed it to this.auto checked: this.auto.checked = !this.checked; and it blows up with Cannot set property 'checked' of undefined

Comment: My bad. `this.props.auto.checked = !this.props.auto.checked`